# build accounting trail balance report performance issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date-arithmetic, accounting

suppose we have journal entries table as follow

```
create table jour_entries 
 (jseq number, 
  j_date date, 
  Eseq number, 
  account_no varchar2(32), 
  debit number, 
  credit number,
  note varchar2(256) );
```

how to build best performance report for trial balance in SQL?  The report columns are

- account_number: is the account number.
- debit_within_month: is the sum of all debits related to account_number starting from 1st of given month till end of that month (or till current day if given date is in current month)
- credit_within_month: is the sum of all credits related to account_number starting from 1st of given month till end of that month (or till current day if given date is current month)
- debit_till_this_day: is the accumulative sum of all debits related to account_number over the year of given date (starting from 1st jan of given date till current day).
- credit_till_this_day: is the accumulative sum of all credits related to account_number over the year of given date (starting from 1st jan of given date till current day).

---

I tried this select:

```
select account_number
      , debit_within_month
      , credit_within_month
      , debit_till_this_day
      , credit_till_this_day
from jour_entries j, 
    (select account_number, sum(debit) debit_within_month, 
                         sum(credit) credit_within_month
              from jour_entries 
              where j_date between trunc(given_date, 'month') and given_date
              group by account_number
    ) j1,
    (select account_number, sum(debit) debit_till_this_day,
                         sum(credit) credit_till_this_day  
              from jour_entries 
              where j_date between trunc(given_date, 'year') and given_date
              group by account_number
    ) j2
wherer j.account_number = j1.account_number
and j.account_number = j2.account_number
```

but I am looking for other solutions (maybe by using analytic functions ) for best performance .

Comment: What did you try already ?

Comment: Performance aside, your solution won't give the correct results for the monthly totals when the given date is not in the current month.  And your logic for the TIL CURRENT totals is faulty too.

Comment: ok, if we are in june 2012, and the user entered date '31-may-2012' the report should give me for each account_number all transactions(debit, credit) happens in may and all transactions from start of year 2012 till end of may.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use the SQL*Plus substitution variable syntax to indicate given_month.   You will need to change this for whatever client you're actually using.

```
select account_number
       , sum ( case when J_date between trunc(&given_date, 'mm') 
                                    and least(sysdate, last_day(&given_date)) 
          then debit else 0 end ) as debit_within_month
       , sum ( case when J_date between trunc(&given_date, 'mm')
                                   and least(sysdate, last_day(&given_date)) 
            then credit else 0 end ) as credit_within_month
       , sum ( case when J_date between trunc(&given_date, 'yyyy') and sysdate)  
               then debit else 0 end ) as debit_til_this_day
      , sum ( case when J_date between trunc(&given_date, 'yyyy') and sysdate)  
              then credit else 0 end ) as credit_til_this_day
from jour_entries
group by account_number
```

**Explanation**

- `trunc()` applied to a date truncates it to the given format mask.  So `trunc(sysdate, 'mm')` gives the first of the month, and the 'yyyy' mask gives the first of the year.
- `last_day()` gives, er,  the last day of the given month.

Comment: This is the way to do it. For a trial balance you need every row in your ledger table, because balance sheet items will be "life to date" balances. Needing every row means a full scan will be more efficient than index lookups, and your only options are to try to scan the table once only as is suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, sounds like something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT JE.Account_no as Account__Number,
    SUM(JE2.debit) as Debit_Within_Month,
    SUM(JE2.credit) as Credit_Within_Month,
    SUM(JE.debit) as Debit_Till_This_Day,
    SUM(JE.credit) as Credit_Till_This_Day
FROM Jour_Entries JE
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT jseq, Account_No, Debit, Credit
        FROM Jour_Entries
        WHERE to_char(j_date, 'YYYY') = 2013 AND to_char(j_date, 'mm') = 2
    ) JE2 ON JE.jseq  = JE2.jseq 
WHERE to_char(j_date, 'YYYY') = 2013 
GROUP BY JE.Account_no
```

Here's the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3c1c/5).

Good luck.